# Какова роль description в messages.json?

Tags: javascript, css, json, css3

Возьмем код для примера [отсюда:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Internationalization)

```
{
    "notificationContent": {
    "message": "You clicked $URL$.",
    "description": "Tells the user which link they clicked.",
    "placeholders": {
      "url" : {
        "content" : "$1",
        "example" : "https://developer.mozilla.org"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`"notificationContent"` - это имя блока.

`"__MSG_notificationContent__"` - так в CSS можно получить строку из `"message"` которая взята из блока `"notificationContent"` и при этом  `$URL$` равен `null or ""`.

`browser.i18n.getMessage("notificationContent", "https://ru.stackoverflow.com");` - так в JS можно получить строку из `"message"` которая взята из блока `"notificationContent"` и при этом `$URL$` равен `"https://ru.stackoverflow.com"`.

`"description"` - зачем он тут нужен и возможно ли его значение запросить?
Возможно его функция в том чтобы описать данный блок разработчику.

`"placeholders"` - в этом блоке я пока до конца не разобрался. Понял, что роль его принимать значение и подставлять в `"message"` и скорее всего используется в JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что формат `JSON` не допускает содержание комментариев в файле. По этому вместо классических комментариев (`//` или `#`) предусмотрено это поле.